# General Formula for finding the point P on a line, so that the sum of distances between P and k random points will be minimal

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

Let's say we have a total of $k$ points in $\Bbb{R}^2$:

$$ P_1 = (u_1, v_1),\ldots,P_k = (u_k, v_k) $$

We also have a line $G$ defined by the formula:
$$ G(x) = \lambda x + \mu $$

I need to find a formula (dependent on $u_i,v_i,\lambda,\mu$) for a point $P = (x, G(x))$ on line $G$, so that **the sum of the square of the distances** between that point $P = (x, G(x))$ and all the other points $$ P_1 = (u_1, v_1),\text{ }...,\text{ }P_k = (u_k, v_k) $$ will be minimal.

By distances I mean Euclidean distances where the distance between $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ is:

$$\sqrt{(y_1-y_2)^2 + (x_1-x_2)^2}$$

so that the square of a distance would be:

$$(y_1-y_2)^2 + (x_1-x_2)^2$$

I tried solving this problem by doing the following:

1) finding a function $f$ such that, given input $x$, outputs the sum of the square of the distances between $P_1,\text{ },..., \text{ }P_k$ and $(x,G(x)) = (x, \lambda x + \mu) $.

2) I looked at the first derivative $(f')$ of the function $f$ and found (dependent on $u_i,v_i,\lambda,\mu$) what $x$ should be so that $f'(x) = 0$ is true. This $x$ should give me the point where $f(x)$ is minimal, since $f$ is a parabola looking upwards. $(f''(x) > 0) \text{ for all }x$.

3) In the end I found that 
$$ x = \frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^k u_i \right)-\lambda\left(\sum_{i=1}^k (\mu-v_i)\right)}{k(\lambda^2+1)}$$
must be true so that the sum of the square of the distances are minimal.

I am still kind of a beginner in calculus and I am not sure if my method of solving the problem is ideal or if my answer is correct. Is there an easier/better way of coming up with this formula? I am aware that my question was long but I would really appreciate it a lot if anyone could take the time and give me some helpful tips. I tried to be clear in asking the question, please let me know if there was anything in my question that is not clear.